# mysql variable for ranking

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, ranking

Please can you assist. I have the following query

```
SET @v:=0;
SELECT @v:=@v+1 as rank, version.id, CAST((st.up-st.down) as SIGNED) 
votes, meta.title FROM version INNER JOIN st ON version.id=st.id INNER JOIN 
meta ON version.id=meta.id ORDER BY votes DESC
```

The problem is that rank increments based on the order of version.id(primary key in version table) and not based on the votes column. I get this problem only when I include the second inner join.

Desired Results:

```
rank | id | votes | title 
 1     12    100    hello
 2     20     50    world
 3     5      20    helloworld
```

Current results:

```
rank | id | votes | title
 1     5     20     helloworld
 2     12    100    hello
 3     20    50     world
```

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample adta and desired results.

Comment: hi sample and desired results included

Comment: @the_big_blackbox sample data means you need to provide sample data for both of your tables which are in query and would be better if you can provide on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 4):

The user-variable-based ranking gets bound before the `ORDER BY`. That means the `rank` values are formally unpredictable, and happen to be by `id` in this query.

So you need to use a subquery. Force the ordering to be correct before applying the `rank` values.

```
 SELECT @v:=@v+1 as rank, t.*
   FROM (
          SELECT version.id, 
                 CAST((st.up-st.down) as SIGNED) votes, 
                 meta.title 
            FROM version 
            JOIN st ON version.id=st.id 
            JOIN meta ON version.id=meta.id 
           ORDER BY votes DESC
        ) t
```

Comment: hi thanks so much still receive the same result, even with the sub query

Comment: @OJones . . . The documentation says "In a SELECT statement, each select expression is evaluated only when sent to the client. " (this is in reference to variables).  Obviously, what you say is true.  Do you know of any reference in the documentation that supports this behavior?

Comment: @GordonLinoff No I've never found it written up exactly. But it's true with all the cross-breed (procedural / declarative hybrid) approaches to this, like oracle `ROWNUM` and this miserable user-variable hack.

Comment: @O.Jones . . . I ask, because I have seen the behavior you describe for `GROUP BY`, but I don't recall it for `ORDER BY`.  The documentation is quite explicit about using *column aliases* derived from variables in such clauses, but not about this situation.  PS.  Based on the documentation, the OP's attempt should work  -- but as I say, I've seen the same problem with `GROUP BY`, so the documentation seems incomplete on this point.

Comment: Well, shoot, maybe I have it wrong.  Wouldn't be the first time (today).

Comment: hi, still struggling a bit I have 2 versions of mysql 1 for a website I run and a local version of wamp. The query runs correctly on the wamp version but not on the website. Do you know which mysql variable or config could be different